# Mobile Safari Odd Border Color Issue

Tags: css, mobile-safari

See this image: http://coreyyoungcorp.com/images/border.png

This only seems to happen when the div has borders but I don't know why.

This is the CSS causing the issue:

```
border-top:1px solid #fff;
border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
```

And this is the full div CSS:

```
#network-menu-row {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    position:relative;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#e5e5e5), color-stop(100%,#ffffff));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5 0%,#ffffff 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5 0%,#ffffff 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5 0%,#ffffff 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e5e5e5 0%,#ffffff 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e5e5e5', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 );
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Anyone know what is causing this? It doesn't even happen all the time. Most of the time it's fine and shows the appropriate colour, but every now and again it decides to show in blue. I thought maybe using the full 6-character hex code may fix it but it didn't, nor did changing the border thickness.

It always works fine on my desktop browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about changing "#fff" to "white" and "#ddd" to "gainsboro"? It probably won't solve it, but it's worth a shot, as I have no idea what could be causing it.

Comment: Having just run a test, the issue is only created when the page is navigated back, and only happens on certain divs. All 10 divs on the page use the same naming and coding, yet only 8 of them have this problem.

Comment: Are there any other colors anywhere in your css?  It could be another selector overriding your border properties.

Comment: Yea I thought about that, but i searched for the colour being created and it wasn't anywhere in my stylesheets. I then googled the colour and saw someone had used a CSS reset and set that as their standard visited link colour, which helped me figure out what was happening.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed the issue. Because the link once click had been "visited", when navigating back the anchor for some reason changed the border colours. Used the following to fix it:

```
a:visited div {
    border:inherit;
}
```